# How can I get SS / SSS ranks in EMS?

Tags: theatrhythm-final-fantasy

When I'm playing EMS tracks without the Stoic bonus, I'm limited to 7,999,999 points. With the Stoic bonus I don't have a chance to activated the Extended Version and so while I get the +2,000,000 bonus I don't get to play the last ~10% of the track.

Is it impossible to get SS / SSS rank in EMS, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Oh, is it the Stoic Bonus that prevents you from getting the extended versions? It's a bit frustrating that I can't play the longer versions of these songs while simultaneously playing for score (Stoic mode).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is certainly possible.

Scoring in this game is calculated by the number of "notes" in the score. If you're playing for stoic (so no extended sequence), the game removes those "extra" notes from It's calculations, but awards you more points per correct hit. If you Full Critical the chart, you will still end up at 7999999 score.

The ranking system is calculated by the points you receive.

- < 7 million : A or less
- 7 million+: S rank
- 9 million+: SS rank
- 9,999,999: SSS rank

The game doesn't care if you miss 10% of the track.